# How to update the status of the suggestion in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web-based safety suggestions program for my company where the employees can submit any safety suggestions they have. Now, I am working on the Administration part of this system. The Admin will be able to see all safety suggestions listed in a table. In the last column of the table, the status will be listed there. When the Admin clicks on the status of one of these suggestion, a new pop-up window (asp.net ajax ModalPopUpExtender) will be appeared with listing all the possible status such as: actioned, approved... etc. And when the Admin selects one of these status, the status of the suggestion will be updated in the database. I wrote the code but still it doesn't update the status of the suggestion, **so could you please help me in modifying it?**

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="900px" CssClass="mGrid" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="alt" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "True" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="DivisionShortcut" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />

                <%-- This to make status be opened and edited through the Ajax ModalPopUp Window --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSuggestionStatus" Text='<%#Eval("Status")%>'
                                        OnClick="lnkSuggestionStatus_Click">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />--%>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalPopUp" style="display:none" />

        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender ID="modalPopUpExtender1"
                                        runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp" 
                                        PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" 
                                        BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle"
                                        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle" 
                                        OkControlID="OKButton">
        </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopUp">

                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StatusList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                                            RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left" DataSourceID="SuggestionStatusDataSource"
                                            DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID">
                        <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="ACTIONED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="APPROVED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="PENDING" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option4" runat="server" Value="TRANSFERRED" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SuggestionStatusDataSource" runat="server"
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server" Text="Confirm" 
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to send an email notification about the safety suggestion to the owner?')" 
                                OnClick="btnSendStatus_Click" />

            <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsStatus SET ID= @statusID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", statusID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name...
    SafetySuggestionsLog: ID, Title, Description, Username, StatusID
    SafetySuggestionsStatus: ID, Status
```

And I am getting the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", statusID);
```

Since your update query did not declare @ID but @statusID, It should be

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", statusID);
```

Comment: Please indicate if this answer solved your problem so we can know your progress

Comment: Actually, it did work with me. Please see my updated question.